# Merge beta and beta-sites

Tags: support, retag-request, meta, synonym-request

[beta-phase](/questions/tagged/beta-phase) (51) and [beta-sites](/questions/tagged/beta-sites) (40) are both being used interchangeably on meta - perhaps they should be merged and synonyms created, or just remove beta-sites?  (Beta-phase has Beta as a synonym.)

It seems that most questions tagged with [beta-sites](/questions/tagged/beta-sites) are also tagged with [design](/questions/tagged/design) although the wiki's don't suggest why this is the case apart from the mention of the different theme:

> **beta** - issues specific to SE 2.0 sites that have been created in Area 51 and are currently in the Beta phase.
>
> **beta-sites** - This tag is used for posts that are related to those Stack Exchange sites which are currently in beta phase. Beta sites have a different website theme as compared to full member (graduate) sites of the Stack Exchange Network. Reputation points requirements for some privileges are different.

I can't see that there is any real difference between them though.